# "This PC" empty when opening files from a Windows 8 store app

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-store-app

I've been having this issue where the Windows 8 modern file open screen won't show me the contents of my PC. When I use an "open file" button in any store app, I am shown the file open screen in some default folder, such as `This PC > Music`. From there, I can navigate to any file in this folder. However, when I choose `parent folder`, the `This PC` folder indicates `This view contains no files or folders`. This means that I cannot access files on my desktop or anywhere else on my local drive.

I've been having this problem on my Surface, both before and after upgrading to Windows 8.1. However, that same dialog works fine on my laptop (I see my local drives and user folders). Any ideas about ways to address this?